# Linq XML query with nested loop

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I would like to read below XML and print the output in following order. Can you pls help with Query?

[image]

10  Subject1    A1
10  Subject2    B1
10  Subject3    C1
20  Subject1    B2
20  Subject2    A1
20  Subject3    C2

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get how you expect `Subject1    C1` to come out of that XML?

Comment: Sorry, there was typo for Subject 3. I have been able to load the Xdocument and declare var with XElement ID but never used Linq before. I can do this in SQL server, but the issue is I lose much of the formatting hence trying to do using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example how you can query in the form you want:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var query = from l in doc.Descendants("L1")
            let id = l.Attribute("id").Value
            from subject in l.Descendants("Subject")
            select new
            {
                Id = id,
                SubjectName = (string)subject.Attribute("SubjectName"),
                Score = (string)subject.Attribute("Score")
            };

foreach (var result in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ Id = 10, SubjectName = Subject1, Score = A1 }
{ Id = 10, SubjectName = Subject2, Score = B1 }
{ Id = 10, SubjectName = Subject3, Score = C1 }
{ Id = 20, SubjectName = Subject1, Score = B2 }
{ Id = 20, SubjectName = Subject2, Score = A1 }
{ Id = 20, SubjectName = Subject3, Score = C2 }
```

Comment: For more _inline madness_ could use a `(query).ToList().ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item))`, substituting `query` with the linq query you suggested. ;)

Comment: Hello, please suggest what changes should be made to display the date in the output. thanks