# Linq XML query with nested loop - 1

Tags: c#, xml, linq

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488217/linq-xml-query-with-nested-loop), if I need to get "date" included in  the output, what changes should be made?

When I included

```
let dt = l.Element("Date").Value
```

It gives, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
var query = from l in doc.Descendants("L1")
            let dt = l.Element("Date").Value
            let id = l.Attribute("id").Value
            from subject in l.Descendants("Subject")
            select new
            {
                Date = dt,
                Id = id,
                SubjectName = (string)subject.Attribute("SubjectName"),
                Score = (string)subject.Attribute("Score")
            };


foreach (var result in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: When you included that, what happened? Note that the XML that you've shown in the other question doesn't have any contents in the `<date>` elements.

Comment: he completed it with "it gives, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
it got lumped into the code block

Comment: fixed the sentence (sort of).

Comment: Note that your xml on the previous question has `<date>` and you are looking for `Date` -- the casing of the element name needs to be consistent.

Comment: Lets say date is string. Tried D Stanley's and Lucas Reis suggestion but it returns                                                                         { Date = , Id = 10, SubjectName = subject1, Score = A1 }
{ Date = , Id = 10, SubjectName = subject2, Score = A2 }
{ Date = , Id = 10, SubjectName = subject2, Score = A3 }
{ Date = , Id = 20, SubjectName = subject4, Score = B1 }
{ Date = , Id = 20, SubjectName = subject5, Score = B2 }
{ Date = , Id = 20, SubjectName = subject6, Score = B3 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your other XML, it does not, as Mr. Skeet mentioned, have anything in the `<date>` elements.  You will need to explicitly handle that if you aren't planning on always having data in there.

You can do something like this:

```
let dt = l.Element("date") == null ? string.Empty : l.Element("date").Value
```

Answer (score 2):

If `l` doesn't have an `Date` element, trying to access `l.Element("Date").Value` will incur an error. You can use a conditional:

```
var query = from l in doc.Descendants("L1")
        let dt = l.Elements("date").Any() 
                 ? l.Element("date").Value
                 : AnyDefaultValueIWantForDate
        let id = l.Attribute("id").Value
        from subject in l.Descendants("Subject")
        select new
        {
            Date = dt,
            Id = id,
            SubjectName = subject.Attribute("SubjectName").Value,
            Score = subject.Attribute("Score").Value
        };
```

(I also added the `.Value` in `SubjectName` and `Score`).

Comment: Is there any data in the `Date` element in the XML? Because in your link where you show a part of it, there is none...

Comment: please use this for testing                   <Root>
<L1 id="10">
<date>2012Jan01</date>
<Subject SubjectName="subject1" Score="A1"/>
<Subject SubjectName="subject2" Score="A2"/>
<Subject SubjectName="subject2" Score="A3"/>
</L1>


<L1 id="20">
<date>2012Jan02</date>
<Subject SubjectName="subject4" Score="B1"/>
<Subject SubjectName="subject5" Score="B2"/>
<Subject SubjectName="subject6" Score="B3"/>
</L1>
</Root>

Comment: edited: changed `"Date"` for `"date"` (XML is case sensitive).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `l` is not null then `l.Element("Date")` is null which would mean that one or more of your `L1` elements does not have a child `Date` element.

The fix would depend on what you want to do with missing dates.  If you want to use `default(DateTime)` as a "magic" date, you could do:

```
let dt = (l.Element("Date") == null ? default(DateTime) : l.Element("Date").Value)
```

Comment: One problem with that unary is that the default datetime will return a datetime, and the l.Element("Date").Value will return a string.  There needs to be a conversion on one side or the other.